# Sequelize require function does not create the models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am aware of sequelize.import's deprecation and , after I have researched basically every single question on this topic , I have reached the last version of my code:
`src/models/message.js`:

```
import sequelize from '.message.js'
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize/types'




module.exports=(sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const Message=sequelize.define("message",{
        text:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING
        }
    })

    Message.associate=models=>{
        Message.belongsTo(models.User)
    }

    return Message
}
```

And `src/models/index.js`:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';



const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
);

const models = {
  User: require('./user')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
  Message: require('./message')(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes),
}

Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
  if ('associate' in models[key]) {
    models[key].associate(models);
  }
});

export { sequelize };

export default models;
```

I have tried every single thing pointed out in previous posts, yet nothing worked, could you please explain what Im doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird to mix up `import` and `require`. Use `import` and call imported model functions directly:

```js
import MessageFactory from './models/message'
import UserFactory from './models/user'
...
const models = {
  User: UserFactory(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
  Message: MessageFactory(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have just done that yet I get the same error: " Cannot find module '.message.js'". In case you are wondering , this is how I export it : `export default MessageFactory=(sequelize,DataTypes)`. Do you maybe know what is the problem ?

Comment: Replace `'.message.js'` with './message.js'

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH !  Have been struggling with this for hours now!